How do I format the string to POST data through XMLHttpRequest in Laravel?
I'm trying to send my data through XMLHttpRequest but don't know how to format the string with all the data
My JS Code:
function savePhotos() {
    var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="_token"]').content;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", saveRoute, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrf); 
    xhr.send("name='test'"); //What do I put here
}

My Controller create function:
 public function create(Request $request)
 {
     $data = $request->all();
     $model = Photo::create([
            'categoryId' => $data['categoryId'],
            'collectionId' => $data['collectionId'],
            'categoryId' => $data['categoryId'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'views' => $data['views'],
            'likes' => $data['likes'],
            'dateUploaded' => $data['dateUploaded'],
            'altText' => $data['altText'],
            'url' => $data['url'],
            'private' => $data['private'],
         ]);
       return redirect()->route("photoIndex");
    }


You want to learn FormData.

...and why xhr and not the fetch API?

Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new question, there are so many examples of this here already.  Did you see or try any of the code in those?

This question is similar to: Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
